# Gmail account works on Outlook, but not Outlook.com, after updating google password

Tags: gmail, outlook.com

I use Outlook (Windows) as well as Outlook.com to access mail and calendar in my Microsoft and Google accounts.

Last night I updated the password for my Google account and was able to update the account settings in Outlook desktop. In that application I am able to access Gmail messages as before, all is good there.

However, after this change, when I try to access Gmail from Outlook.com, I now get the following error:

> 400 Bad request. An error occurred when you tried to access your
> mailbox because a server with information about you and your mailbox
> couldn't be found.

I would like to get this working again as it was before, being able to access Gmail from both Outlook and Outlook.com.

Answer (score 0):

[Sign in with app passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) **>** [App passwords revoked after password change](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en#:%7E:text=App%20passwords%20revoked%20after%20password%20change)

> #### App passwords revoked after password change
>
> To help protect your account, we revoke your app passwords when you change your Google Account password. To continue to use an app with your Google Account, [create a new app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833#app-passwords).
>
> **Tip:** If the app offers "Sign in with Google," we recommend you use that feature to connect the app to your Google Account.